# Vue: Losing context of "this" inside function promise

Tags: vue.js

I am losing the context of this on the "then" portion of my Promise.  I marked the first debugger, which when I type in `this`, shows the value as the Vue component.  I continue on and when I hit the next debugger statement inside the `then` portion of the Promise, the value of `this` is undefined even when using the fat arrow syntax.

**Parent component**

```html
<Modal
    @emitshowflashmsg="handleShowCouponModal"
>
```

**Child component (`Modal.vue`)**

```js
methods: {

  showFlash: function(msg, bool) {
    let data = {msg, bool}
    this.$emit('emitshowflash', data)
  },

  updateShippingAddress: function() {

    debugger
    // `this` has a value here
    axios.post('/api/act/address', { 
        street_address: this.$refs.streetAddress.value ? this.$refs.streetAddress.value : "",
        apartment: this.showSecondAddressLine ? this.$refs.apartment.value : "",
        city: this.$refs.city.value ? this.$refs.city.value : "",
        state: this.$refs.state.value ? this.$refs.state.value : "",
        zip: this.$refs.zip.value ? this.$refs.zip.value : ""
    })

    .then((response) => {
        debugger
        // `this` is undefined here
        if(response.data.success) {
            let msg = "Address updated!"
            this.showFlash(msg, true)
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("errrrr")
        let msg = "Not valid address. Please check address again."
        this.showFlash(msg, true)

    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Ignoring the debugger for a minute, are you getting any actual errors? If `this` was not your Vue component in the `then()` callback, I imagine you would get something like _"this.showFlash is not a function"_. Is that what's happening?

Comment: @Phil yea, that's how I noticed there was an issue.  `this.showFlash` is triggering the catch and logging `errrrr`.  When I removed `this.showFlash()`, the catch is not triggered

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you're using an arrow function in `then()` and `catch()`? Perhaps your browser is running an older version of your script from cache

Comment: Yep, positive.  I am using Incognito in Chrome but just to be sure, I cleared cache and made a new instance and the same thing happens.  And yea, definitely using the fat arrow.  I copied that code straight from my editor and just added the comments in

Comment: yep, `showFlash` is a function listed under the "methods" of the component.

Comment: @Phil sure, just added

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem in a [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/philbrown/of7d6bsc/13/) but it all works as expected. I can only assume then that the code in your question doesn't actually match your real code

Comment: Just noticed your parent component is listening for `emitshowflashmsg` but you are emitting `emitshowflash`. Now, that wouldn't cause the issue you're seeing but it certainly won't do what you expect

Comment: yikes, good catch -- thank you

Comment: @Phil Aside of that, `emitshowflashmsg` is calling `handleShowCouponModal` method (from modal's parent component), but only modal's `updateShippingAddress` method is shown. Real mess :)